# Finding minimum values in a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a list of dicts like:

```
l = [{'dist':56, 'responder':N}, {'dist':26, 'responder':N}, {'dist':86, 'responder':N}]
```

And I want to return the 2 smallest distances ('dist') as well as the value for 'responder', what is the best way to do that in Python?

Comment: try `min(l, key=lambda d: d['dist'])`.

Comment: @Cfreak, well I know that I can find the minimum distances by using a list comprehension and using min() but I still don't know how to retain the values of 'responder'

Comment: it is rare for a programming task to have `the best way`

Comment: @Bakuriu's solution returns the smallest, but to return two of the smallest by sort, you should use ``sorted`` instead of ``min``.

Comment: @user2767074 the point is you should try something and see if it works. Then ask how to fix it if it doesn't. SO is not intended to be a place where people do your code for you.

Comment: `heapq.nsmallest` is quite a good way to find the 2 smallest of anything.

Comment: @Cfreak not necessarily. You'll see below that I got basic input from Bakuriu and was able to implement it on my own, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Bakuriu's solution with a modification:

```
l = [{'dist':56, 'responder':'n'}, {'dist':26, 'responder':'n'}, \
{'dist':86, 'responder':'n'}]

smallestTwo = sorted(l, key=lambda d: d['dist'])[:2]
```

Output:

```
[{'responder': 'n', 'dist': 26}, {'responder': 'n', 'dist': 56}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try sort your list first

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(l, key=itemgetter('dist'), reverse=True)
[{'responder': 'N', 'dist': 86}, {'responder': 'N', 'dist': 56}, {'responder': 'N', 'dist': 26}]
```

then slice first two elements

```
>>> sorted(l, key=itemgetter('dist'), reverse=True)[:2]
[{'responder': 'N', 'dist': 86}, {'responder': 'N', 'dist': 56}]
```

and get responders from them

```
>>> map(itemgetter('responder'), sorted(l, key=itemgetter('dist'), reverse=True)[:2])
['N', 'N']
```

Comment: I know about heapq, and advocate it, but cosider it a bit complicated for this question