# Max and min value in list of dicts where each dict key has a value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max, min

All the answers I found to this seem to make you have to [specify which key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320871/in-list-of-dicts-find-min-value-of-a-common-dict-field) you want to find the max/min for e.g. [Finding minimum values in a list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759374/finding-minimum-values-in-a-list-of-dicts).

I have a list of dicts like:

```
 [
{
    1:34,
    2:12,
    3:24
},
{
    1:121,
    2:1211,
    3:1891
},
{
    1:191,
    2:8991,
    3:3232
}
]
```

So here it would pull out 12 and 8991.

And I want to find the max and min of all the values in this list of dicts.

How do I do this without having to specify each key separately (e.g. 1,2,3) - in the real version I have 20+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the values, then find the min and max:

```
from itertools import chain

flattened = list(chain(*(d.values() for d in list_of_dicts)))
print(min(flattened))
print(max(flattened))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension or generator expression.

```
max([max(d.values()) for d in data])
```

Comment: You can use a generator instead of a comprehension by removing the `[]`.